# Notation for spectral decomposition

Tags: spectral-theory

One of the conditions for the spectral decompositions $P_{\lambda} (\lambda \in Sp(A))$ of diagonalizable operator $A$ acting upon a finite dimensional vectorspace is $P_{\lambda} P_{\mu} = \delta_{\lambda, \mu} P_{\mu}$.

What does $\delta_{\lambda, \mu}$ mean? The notes that I am using do not define it, and I am struggling to find it online.

Comment: There is no generally defined notation. You need to specify your operations here. What is $Sp(A)$? A space? What is the value of $P_\lambda$?

Comment: $Sp(A)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$, and $P_{\lambda}$ is the projection onto the eigenspace $V_{\lambda}$ (where $V$ is the vectorspace which contains $A$) along the linear subspace $\displaystyle \sum_{\mu \in Sp(A), \mu \neq \lambda} V_{\mu}$

Answer (score 0):

It is a the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Kronecker%20delta,of%20variables%20i%20and%20j.), a function of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ --- equal to one when $\lambda=\mu$, and zero otherwise. It is expressing that $P_\mu$ and $P_\nu$ are orthogonal ('perpendicular').